# No plugin goals bound to a maven phase

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Quite new in maven. By reading document of maven at [official website](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), I know in the default lifeCycle, there are 21 phases including `validate`, `initialize`, `generate-sources`, `process-sources`, `generate-resources`, `process-resources`, `compile`, `process-classes`, `generate-test-sources`, `process-test-sources`, `generate-test-resources`, `process-test-resources`, `test-compile`, `test`, `prepare-package`, `package`, `pre-integration-test`, `integration-test`, `post-integration-test`, `verify`, `install` and `deploy`.

But when I see [Built-in Lifecycle Bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings), I found that there is no plugin goals binding to phases like `validate`, `initialize`, `verify`, etc.
So if I run command `mvn package`, are phases without plugin goals going to be executed?
Or plugins goals for these phases are fixed and we do not have control of them so there is no need to write them in the document. Every time these phases like `validate`, `initialize`, `verify`, etc. will be executed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First yes there are no plugins bound to the phases `validate`, `initialize` and `verify` by default (and some other phases as well).

If you run `mvn package` all phases will be executed but if there is no plugin bound to a phase you can't see it. If you run `package` phase all the phases including `package` phase itself will be executed from the beginning `validate`, `initialize`, `generate-sources`and so on...

Sometimes it is useful to bind plugins to phases like `initialize`. This is the case for example for the [build-number-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html).

Phases before `verify` like `pre-integration-test`, `integration-test` and `post-integration-test` are useful to run integration tests which can be handled by [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). The unit tests are handled by the [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).

Phases like `generate-sources` are often used by source generating plugins like [jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.3/index.html) or others like annotation processor generation plugins...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you mean when I run mvn package, phase initialize would also be run but nothing is done in this phase because no plugin goals bound to it?

Comment: @Frankie It's more that no plugins are bound to `initialize` in the default lifecycle. But, your POM could use a plugin goal that binds to it by default and so it would execute. You could also have another lifecycle that has a binding to it.

Comment: @Tunaki OK, I got it. Maven only execute plugin goals. Because no default plugin goals binds to phase initialize in default life cycle, I cannot see this phase in default life cycle. If I has a pom that has a plugin binding to initialize, this plugin would be executed so that I can see the phase. Phase is a just a abstraction to indicate order. Right?